# Plato - against teaching philosophy to children

Tags: reference-request, plato

I'm trying to hunt down a half-remembered quote from Plato, possibly from the *Republic,* where he actually argues AGAINST teaching children philosophy too early, in the fears it will confuse them and lead them to relativism.  It seems to me related to the "noble lie" but I didn't find it in that section.

Comment: Rep. bk 7, 538-41 perhaps "There is a danger lest they should taste the dear delight too early; for youngsters, as you may have observed, when they first get the taste in their mouths, argue for amusement, and are always contradicting and refuting others in imitation of those who refute them;"

Comment: @sand1 I think this is the passage I'm looking for, can you please make this an actual answer so it can be voted on, and potentially accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from *The Republic, Book 7*: 538-41

> There is a danger lest they should taste the dear delight too early; for youngsters, as you may have observed, when they first get the taste in their mouths, argue for amusement, and are always contradicting and refuting others in imitation of those who refute them;

http://www.literaturepage.com/read/therepublic-287.html